# custom symfony2 bundle installation with composer from private bitbucket repository

Tags: php, composer-php, bitbucket

I'm desperately trying to install my Symfony Bundle via composer. I did following things:

- created a bitbucket git repo in the root folder of the bundle (SymfonyProject/src/My/Bundle)
- created a composer.json file:

  ```
  {
      "name": "my/bundle",
      "description": "my desc",
      "type" : "symfony-bundle",
      "require": {
          "foreign/bundle": "dev-master"
      },
      "license": "proprietary",
      "authors": [
          {
              "name": "Me",
              "email": "me@mycompany.com"
          }
      ],
      "minimum-stability": "dev",
      "autoload": {
         "psr-0": { "My\\Bundle\\": "" }
      },
      "target-dir" : "My/Bundle"
  }
  ```
- then i've created a testproject and added following to composer.json in the symfony root:

  ```
  "require" : {
       "my/bundle" : "dev-master"
  },
  "repositories" : [
        "type" : "vcs",
        "url" : "https://myusername:password@bitbucket.org/mycompany/myrepo.git"
  ]
  ```
- i call composer update my/bundle -vvv and get the following output (uninteresting stuff is removed):

  ```
   Loading composer repositories with package information
   Executing command (CWD): git clone --mirror 'https://username:****@bitbucket.org/mycompany/myrepo.git'
   '/home/myname/.composer/cache/vcs/https---repocachedir/'
   Executing command (/home/myname/.composer/cache/vcs/https---repocachedir/): git show-ref --tags
   Executing command (/home/myname/.composer/cache/vcs/https---repocachedir/): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
   Executing command (/home/myname/.composer/cache/vcs/https---repocachedir/): git branch --no-color
   Executing command (/home/myname/.composer/cache/vcs/https---repocachedir/): git show 'master':composer.json
   Executing command (/home/myname/.composer/cache/vcs/https---repocachedir/): git log -1 --format=%at 'master'
   Reading composer.json of my/bundle (master)
   Reading /home/myname/.composer/cache/vcs/https---repocachedir/09esdfsdfdb74ce0998ddsdfsd59028969b8edef35f872 from cache
   **Importing branch master (dev-master)**
   Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json
  ```

The last output is "importing branch master" which is right, isnt it? After that the packagist stuff is fetched. Composer install wont work either, package will not be installed. What am I doing wrong?

If somebody could enlighten me, i would be very pleased!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup working using type "git".

Also it looks like it using a cached version?

Could this be empty?

It can be found and removed from (from Composer docs):

"Defaults to $home/cache on unix systems and C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Composer on Windows."

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer. Ive already removed the cached files for the output above. Composer will do the same thing. The cached repo seems to be empty, except the composer.json (which is the hashed file above)... Why?

Comment: Are you able to checkout the library from bitbucket, with the key that composer's using? I'm wondering if it could be a permissions thing (as things often are).

Comment: Are you setting the full autoload path in the library's composer.json? Maybe composer can't see what it's meant to be fetching?

Comment: What I mean is, is everything in "root" as the composer file above suggests?

Comment: The Doctrine Common library puts everything within /lib
I've always followed that convention.

"autoload": { "psr-0": { "Doctrine\\Common": "lib/" }}

Comment: in the root of the repo = root of the created bundle (which contains all files i need), you mean that?